# Return subclass from abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have a base class 'Color' with a sunclass 'Primary' and yet another two 'Blue' and 'Red'

Color requires:

```
abstract class Color {
    Future<Color> foo({required int index});
}
```

so each color will override it. But I want to override the function in the Primary so the body is always the same:

```
abstract class Primary extends Color {
    Future<Primary> foo({required int index}) async {
      //In this case, I want the return type to be the same as the object calling it
      return SpecificPrimaryColorOfSubclass(
        //...
      );
    }
}
```

In this case, red would not have the method foo, because its already declared in Primary

```
class Red extends Primary {
   //Can call foo and return Red without declaring it
}
```

However, I would like to return the actual primary color (say 'Red') instead of 'Primary.' Can I construct the returning object with the type of "this" using something like ?

Comment: I feel like this question needs more details. Also, are you mixing up the words superclass and subclass? Is Primary a subclass of Color, and Red a subclass of Primary?

Comment: It's kind of confusing what the class hierarchy is intended to be and which class is abstract.  This question would be much clearer if you provided a *complete* code example instead of disconnected snippets.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I did mix them up. Thanks! Edited..

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to return the class type, but perhaps usage of generic types would help a bit:

```dart
abstract class Color<T> {
  Future<T> foo(int index);
}

class Primary<T extends Color> extends Color<T>{
  @override
  Future<T> foo(int index) {
    // TODO: implement foo
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}

class SpecificPrimaryColorOfSuperclassRed extends Primary<SpecificPrimaryColorOfSuperclassRed>{

}
```

In this case, SpecificPrimaryColorOfSuperclassRed's method `foo` is returning a type `SpecificPrimaryColorOfSuperclassRed`. So every class you create just needs to inherit from `Color` to be able to be the type that `foo` will return

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible for the simple reason that `Primary` can't know what the constructors look like of its subclasses. They might have no public constructors or only constructors with parameters.